# Application defined error creating new pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

Hi this macro worked on one excel sheet, however as soon as I tried using this on the same copy of the excel sheet, I encounter the application-defined/object-defined error. I am trying to create a pivot table on a new sheet, using a dynamic range. Any help would be appreciated in fixing my code

```
Sub CreatePivot()

Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Report!" & Sheets("Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion _ 
:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

When I run the debug, I get the error at:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Report!"
```

Comment: When the error occurs, what line is marked on the Editor?

Comment: How do I specifically find out? When I run the debug, it runs through until the first line of the ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Report!" but does not specifically highlight that line. @CLR

Comment: FYI not sure if it's a typo when copy/pasting to SO, but you need to bring the `Sheets("Report").Range("A1")...` line on to the same with the `"Report!" & ` ...or just add another `_` after `&`.

Comment: That is a typo, edited the main post to reflect the correct form

Comment: Your code, once I move the _ breaks into the right place works for me.

Comment: @CLR could you clarify?

Comment: I mean that the code you've provided above does work (for me) if the underscores are put in the correct end of line positions.

Comment: @CLR I've modified the code in the main body again to reflect your comment, however I'm still returning the same error. Is something wrong with my data range?

Comment: Have you tried manually creating a pivot, to ensure there's nothing wrong with your source data?

Answer (score 0):

Try the dynamic code below to set your `PivotTable`, explanation inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivot()

Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim wsNew               As Worksheet
Dim SrcRng              As Range

' add a new worksheet and name it "Pivot"
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"

' set the Source range of the Pivot Cache
Set SrcRng = Sheets("Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

' set Pivot Cache for Pivot Table
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal))

' === for DEBUG Only ===
Debug.Print SrcRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = wsNew.PivotTables("PivotTable4") ' check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' Pivot table object is nothing >> create it

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable4" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = wsNew.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=wsNew.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable4")

    With PvtTbl
        ' modify the resy of the Pivot-Table properties

    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! However I am returning the same object defined error. Is it something to do with my source data? Debug shows the error at With PvtTbl

Comment: @CuriousStudent when running in debug mode, at what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: The code runs through until it hits the line                                                
        With PvtTbl
        ' modify the resy of the Pivot-Table properties

Comment: @CuriousStudent try edited code, what are you getting in the `Debug.Print` line ?

Comment: it doesn't make it that far, code now breaks at Set SrcRng = Sheets("Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion line

Comment: @CuriousStudent so you have a sheet name "Report" ? where does your Pivot Range lies in that sheet ?

Comment: So the pivot table I'm trying to create, uses data from the sheet called "Report" and the pivot range is dynamic which is another variable I tried to fix.

Comment: @CuriousStudent can you tell where does the Pivot Range start ? do you have some kind of anchor for the start ?

Comment: It starts at A15 i believe

Comment: So you need to use `Sheets("Report").Range("A15").CurrentRegion` , but the question is if that range is consistent ? or moving all the time ?

Comment: Ok, making progress now, the pivot table runs, but the error is still appearing. Any tips?

Comment: Still at the same place. I run debug and as i go through each line, it immediately breaks at ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _"Report!"                                                                                       I reverted back to my origina code, but using your suggestion of starting at A15